# How to include external jar in javafxports Project?

Tags: java, android, gradle, javafx, javafxports

I am trying javafxports using gluon plugin on netbeans. JavaFx works on android but if i include a jar like jsoup, i get only black screen on android.However, all is working fine on Desktop.

I have tried including jsoup both as gradle online dependency as well as local jar files. I am using a class from my another project named Result.java which imports jsoup.

--------Modified Part of my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) //jsoup-1.12.1.jar
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.6'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'connectivity', 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
        androidSdk = '/home/oreo/Android/sdk/'   
        compileSdkVersion =29
        buildToolsVersion ="29.0.0"
    }
}
```

-------imports used by Result.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import org.jsoup.select.*;
```

-------Main.java

```
package com.ignoux;

import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Screen;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane root=new GridPane();
        Label l=new Label("Text will be here");
        Button b=new Button("Fetch");
        b.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            l.setText(Result.getUrlList());
        });

        root.addRow(0, b);
        root.addRow(1, l);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("JavaFX WebView Example");
        Rectangle2D primaryScreenBounds = Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds();
        //set Stage boundaries to visible bounds of the main screen
        primaryStage.setX(primaryScreenBounds.getMinX());
        primaryStage.setY(primaryScreenBounds.getMinY());
        primaryStage.setWidth(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());
        primaryStage.setHeight(primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Program is to only learn creating desktop and android apps with same java librarys (and ios if possible). I previously tried hello world button and it works but modifying it to include jar is not working. I just want to print Result class output in label on pressing button to check how stuff works.

Please help me.

Comment: Did you check the logs? Black screen usually means there was an exception. Use `adb logcat` to find out

Comment: Thanks you helped me. I checked and added internet permission in android Manifest and now all works. Previously i thought that gluon plugin will add permissions itself but its not.